# Display PDF in Asp.net Page Not working on IE

Tags: asp.net, pdf, byte, response, httpresponse

I'm trying to display a PDF in a Asp.net page using

```
  <object data= ..../>
```

the pdf is generated in the HttpResponse using a byte Array like that

```
 **Response.OutputStream.Write(pdfArrayByte, 0, LengthofPdfArray);**
```

for the Response i gave it as Headers :

```
 **Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename.pdf");**
```

Now the problem is that when i call this page on Chrome it displays the PDF file but when i call it in IE10 it download it instead of displaying it ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'v found the solution, 
for the record, if you get the same problem as mine , make sure that your machine has a PDF reader installed , i'v just installed ***adob reader*** and **Vingoo** , the problem is solved :)